# If the tangents to parabola $y^2=4ax$ at $(at^2,2at)$ and $(as^2,2as)$ meet at $(p,q)$, then $a^2(t-s)^2=q^2-4ap$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

> If the tangents to the parabola $y^2 = 4ax$ at the points $(at^2, 2at)$ and $(as^2, 2as)$ meet at the point $(p, q)$. Show that 
>   $$a^2(t - s)^2 = q^2 - 4ap$$

My work so far: Using $yy = 2a(x + x)$ for point $(at^2, 2at)$, I got the equation to be 
$$yt = x + at^2$$ For point $(as^2, 2as)$, I got 
$$ys = x + as^2$$

Then I put in $(p, q)$ for $x$ and $y$ and got 
$$qt = p + at^2 \quad\text{and}\quad qs = p + as^2$$ This is where I'm stuck, because if I equate them, one of the variables will cancel out but all the variables are involved.

Comment: You should post the work that you've done and where you got stuck. This will help answerers tailor their responses. After all, it's possible that you made a simple error in calculation; writing-up a solution for others to read often helps me identify such errors in my own work.

Comment: Did you calculate the slope correctly. Note that the parabola is not the usual way (it is rotated by $90^\circ$)

Comment: Thank you very much @Blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

calculate the point of intersection, after writing the equation of tangent using T=0.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand the image

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$a t^2 - q t + p = 0 \qquad a s^2 - q s + p = 0$$
Therefore, $s$ and $t$ are the two roots of the quadratic equation
$$am^2 - qm + p = 0$$
By [Vieta's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Example),
$$s + t = \frac{q}{a} \qquad s t = \frac{p}{a}$$
so that
$$a^2(s-t)^2 = a^2\left(s^2 - 2 s t + t^2\right) = a^2\left((s+t)^2 - 4 s t\right) = a^2\left(\frac{q^2}{a^2}-\frac{4p}{a}\right) = q^2-4ap$$
as desired. $\square$